# discord.py - discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): - even though message is under 2000 characters

Tags: python, discord.py

```
      msg = discord.Embed(
           title = country_name + ' Coronavirus cases',
           colour = discord.Colour.blue(),


           )
       msg.set_thumbnail(url='https://www.worldometers.info/img/flags/'+ country_code +'-flag.gif')
       msg.add_field(name='**Total Cases**', value = total_cases, inline = False)
       msg.add_field(name='**Deaths**', value = total_deaths, inline = False)
       msg.add_field(name='**Recovered**', value = total_recovered, inline = False)
       await message.channel.send(embed=msg)
```

Error:

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In embed.fields.1.value: This field is required
```

I got the error, looked it up and it said something along the lines of 'this happens when there is more than 2000 characters', my message is less than 100. My code grabs data from a website and sends it through an embedded message on discord. Any help or suggestions are helpful.

Comment: The error is an `Invalid Form Body`. https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/topics/opcodes-and-status-codes#json-json-error-codes
This has nothing to do with "more than 2000 characters". I suspect you are using a very old discord.py library version. Do `python -m pip freeze` and tell us your version

Comment: `discord==1.0.1
discord.py==1.2.5

Comment: uninstall `discord==1.0.1` `python -m pip uninstall discord` and try again

Comment: I still get the same error as before.

Comment: `embed.fields.1.value: This field is required` make sure the value is a string.

Comment: Yes they are strings

Comment: It works if I change the data to `'test'` but not if i do `str()` around the variable

Comment: I had this same problem, and fixed it by making sure no values were set to `None`

Answer (score 0):

I just got the same error and I figured out the reason was that you were trying to send an embed of a NoneType. Be sure to check that the values total_cases, deaths and recoveries are not just empty strings

Answer (score 0):

Although I was using discord.js, I found that it was the command options that were causing the errors. For me, the option name contained a space causing the `Invalid Form Body` error.